# Terraform code for "backup_blob_container_uri"

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

```
resource "azurerm_analysis_services_server" "server" {
  name                    = "analysisservicesserver"
  location                = "northeurope"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                     = "S0"
  admin_users             = ["myuser@domain.tld"]
  enable_power_bi_service = true
backup_blob_container_uri = ("https://${STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/${CONTAINER NAME}%s", Blob SAS TOKEN)
```

*Storage Firewall disable

*Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="Invalid backup blob container 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'. Azure blob storage documentation can be found here:  [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2106906"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2106906%22)

*I am able to add same container via portal without any error

*I also try to copy and past "Blob SAS URL" directly from storage still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Tested in my environment getting the same error even changing the provider version. Might `azurerm_analysis_services_server` outdated for `backup_blob_container_uri`

[image]

You can refer this [***Github***](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/3721) Disccusion there was same error reported long back you can follow with them might be there will be new release for this to sort out this error.